# Using Tor Browser to download files

Tags: tor

If I download something, such as a TV series from a filesharing site via the Tor browser - saving the file to my PC - then put it on a flash drive, will my IT department see that I am downloading this?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Assumpions:

- when you say 'my PC' you mean your work PC, which belongs to your company
- your IT department does auditing on what files are saved on a PC
- your IT department monitors insertion of USB flash drives
- your IT department monitors installation of programs such as Tor
- your IT department monitors network usage and can detect Tor activity

If any of the above is not true, you have *less* chances of being detected.

**BUT**

- I am pretty sure what you are doing is illegal, unless your day job is to download TV series via Tor
- I think (but am not sure) that this is considered "bad practice", as you are not helping the Tor community but instead are freeloading on someone else's bandwidth and CPU power, not to mention the load on the Tor network

Comment: Downloading files is not bad practice within the Tor network. The problem is excessive downloading and in particular torrenting, which puts tremendous strain on the network due to torrent clients making a huge number of connections to a huge number of people.